# ArcGIS Server is truncating the WHERE clause when sending query to SQL Server

Tags: arcgis-server

When I make a query request to a map layer with some WHERE clause to filter the response, the ArcGIS Server truncates the WHERE condition while executing the query on SQL Server.

I am dealing with very large data set of approx 600 millions. The ArcGIS version is 10.4.1

The map layer is bound with a SQL view.

I am querying map layer with following condition:

where: ReadRate30Days <= 100 AND ReadRate30Days >= 0
orderByFields: ReadRate30Days DESC

Ideally in SQL Sever the query should be genarted like below by ArcGIS Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM OAWarehouse.Map_PM_Electric_Service_Point_View) a
WHERE ( (  ( ReadRate3Days <= 100 AND ReadRate3Days >= 0 ) ) AND ( ReportingDate >= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' and ReportingDate <= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' )) 
  AND (Shape.STIntersects(geography::STGeomFromWKB(@P1,@P2)) = 1) 
ORDER BY  ReadRate3Days DESC
```

but it is generated like this in SQL Server

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM OAWarehouse.Map_PM_Electric_Service_Point_View) a
```

I am not able to understand this behaviour ?

[image: query call]

[image: actual query in SQL server by arcgis server]

[image: truncated query]

Comment: I think your question could be improved by adding an explanation of why you think the where clause is truncated. It is unclear to me how the two screenshots of SSMS relate to the question.

Comment: i have updated the description. hope it will help you understand

Comment: Sorry, I don't. All I see is a truncated SQL statement in SSMS, but it is unclear where you got that statement from. For all we know, it could be truncated by the WhoIsActive tool, or even by the web server. Did you try the *Query (Post)* button? Does ArcGIS give any error messages? If so, please update the question and add those.

Comment: ArcGIS takes care to submit SQL as requested, but it also has its own requirements to determine table contents, so you may be mistaking which query is submitted when.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you are querying a layer of a map service. The where clause of a query, performed on a map service does not require the SELECT part. The Where Clause should only be the WHERE clause as you have stated above, so in this case: WHERE ( (  ( ReadRate3Days <= 100 AND ReadRate3Days >= 0 ) ) AND ( ReportingDate >= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' and ReportingDate <= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' )) 
  AND (Shape.STIntersects(geography::STGeomFromWKB(@P1,@P2)) = 1) 
ORDER BY  ReadRate3Days DESC